# iOS Facebook SDK 3.1 openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions: Detect when user is not granting access

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-framework

I need to know when a user has not granted Facebook access to my app during openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions execution. (Not granted meaning the switch is set to 'OFF' under Settings->Facebook->My App.)

Here is the error when not granted:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x1fd46780 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason}

For comparison, here is the error for no network:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x1edf2eb0 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x1ed47a20 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.facebook.com/method/auth.iosauthorizeapp, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.facebook.com/method/auth.iosauthorizeapp, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}}

Is there a fool-proof way to detect when a user is not granted? Do I just look for error code 2 and one key/value pair in the UserInfo dictionary?

I wish Facebook gave us a `BOOL granted` like in `ACAccountStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler`.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

@peter-warbo: I didn't find a GOOD solution. I'm using this:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:FACEBOOK_READ allowLoginUI:YES 
    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

    // find error for not granted
    if(error && error.code == 2) {
        NSDictionary *userInfo = error.userInfo;
        if(userInfo && userInfo.count == 1) {
            [self fallbackLogin];
            return;
        }
    }
    [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
}];

- (void)fallbackLogin {

    // use deprecated
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:FACEBOOK_READ allowLoginUI:YES
completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
          [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
    }];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for permissions using this code:

```
- (void)checkForPermissions {
    // We will request the user's public profile and the user's birthday
    // These are the permissions we need:
    NSArray *permissionsNeeded = @[@"basic_info", @"email"];
    // Request the permissions the user currently has
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/permissions"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          //If there is error, handle it accordingly.

                          //Results contains all the permissions user has granted the app.
                          //If you do not have the desired permissions, reauthorize the app
                          // Ask for the missing permissions
                          //requestPermissions = array of permissions to be asked
                          [FBSession.activeSession
                           requestNewReadPermissions:requestPermissions
                           completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                               //Handle the session object as per your requirements.
                           }];
                      }];
}
```

Hope this helps.